# Apache Camel Grape: Change groovy repository directory

Tags: groovy, apache-camel, wildfly

Camel route example:

```
from("direct:loadCamelFTP").
   to("grape:org.apache.camel/camel-ftp/2.15.2");
```

Groovy documentation explains the default repository is located in`~/.groovy/grape` and can be changed using `groovy -Dgrape.root=/repo/grape yourscript.groovy`

What is the proper way to do this?
Is there a configuration option in camel or can I set the property in Wildfly-9.0 configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately Grape repository is JVM-level setting, so you have to configure it on the container level. For example for Spring Boot:

```
java -Dgrape.root=/repo/grape -jar camel-app.jar
```

For Karaf/ServiceMix/Fuse that would be adding `grape.root=/repo/grape` to the `KARAF_HOME/etc/system.properties` file.

For WildFly that would be adding the following lines to your `standalone.xml`:

```
<system-properties>
    <property name="grape.root" value="/root/grape"/>
</system-properties>
```